# Select a tab bar item programmatically (not using UITabBarController)

Tags: ios, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have a view derived from UIViewControler (not UITabBarController). In this view I added a tab bar with several tab bar items. I used the UITabBarDelegate to allow the view to do something when users tap on each tab bar item.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate {

    func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem!) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

My question is how we can programmatically select the first tab bar item when the view is first loaded? Note that I would want the first tab item to be in "active" state also.

Again, I'm not using UITabBarController

Thanks

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
[tabBar setSelectedItem: [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Which in swift, I think would be:

```
tabBar.selectedItem = tabBar.items![0] as UITabBarItem
```

Comment: Thanks Foster. I actually have to write this code:
`tabBar.selectedItem = tabBar.items![0] as UITabBarItem`

However, I would want to simulate the "tap" event on the first tab. Is that possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you saying the delegate method tabBar(_:didSelectItem:) isn't called when you do tabBar.selectedItem = tabBar.items![0] as UITabBarItem ?

Comment: Yes. That's what I meant. That code just set the tab as "active" and doesn't fire `tabBar(_:didSelectItem:)`

Comment: Maybe you should call that method yourself after setting the selected item.

Comment: Yes. Marked your answer as accepted. That's all we can do I guess to archive the same result as "tap" on the first tab.

Comment: Directly modifying a tab bar managed by a tab bar controller is not allowed. Got the exception!! What worked for me is: self.tabBarController?.tabBar.selectedItem = 2

Comment: @ChanchalRaj self.tabBarController?.tabBar.selectedItem = 2 (UITabBarItem here) gave me exception. Calling `didSelect()` manually worked for me.

Comment: @Foster Bass : calling the `tabBar(_:didSelectItem:)` method goes against its purpose because this method must be fired automatically by its delegate definition.

Answer (score 20):

Swift 3:

```
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0 // (or any other existing index)
```

Answer (score 6):

In swift if tabbar is used not tabbarcontroller set default select

```
var tabbar:UITabBar?//if declare like this

tabbar!.selectedItem = self.tabbar!.items![0] as? UITabBarItem
```

or

```
let tabbar = UITabBar()//if declare and initilize like this

tabbar.selectedItem = self.tabbar.items![0] as? UITabBarItem
```

Comment: `as? UITabBarItem` is redundant, at least for newer versions of Swift, and you will get the warning: _Conditional cast from 'UITabBarItem' to 'UITabBarItem' always succeeds_

Answer (score 5):

if you inside UITabBarController you can use`self.selectedIndex = // set target index`

Answer (score 0):

Before select active tab bar item on viewDidLoad event

[self.tabBar setSelectedItem: [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0]];

Answer (score -1):

In Xamarin.ios, we can use like this
mainTabBarController.selectedIndex=3;