# Can not select tabbar item programmatically in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

I have `UIViewcontroller` having `UITabbar` now i want first tabbar item should be selected by default.
I tried accepted answer of below link 
[Select a tab bar item programmatically (not using UITabBarController)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29286683/select-a-tab-bar-item-programmatically-not-using-uitabbarcontroller?rq=1)

I tried code:

```
class ABC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var tabbar: UITabBar! 

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true) 
        tabbar.selectedItem = tabbar.items?.first as UITabBarItem 
    }
}
```

but getting error

> "Expression type '@lvalue [UITabBarItem]?' is ambiguous without more
>   context"

Comment: Try: `tabBar.selectedItem = tabBar.items?.first`

Comment: @koen getting same error

Comment: Please share the code where you set up your `UIViewController`.

Comment: @IBOutlet var tabbar: UITabBar!
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
         super.viewDidAppear(true)
         tabbar.selectedItem = tabbar.items[0] as UITabBarItem
}

Comment: @koen I have edited Question as per your suggestion

Comment: Are you using a storyboard? Make sure to connect the tabbar to your VC.

Comment: @koen Yes It is connected as didselect delegate method is calling .

Comment: @koen any sugetion ??